# Can't start appium inspector and arc command from console

Tags: android, testing, appium

hej everybody. I'm new in appium, so excuse for obvious questions. I need start to test with Android device/emulator using appium.
I have next configuration:

1. AS 1.1.0
2. Appium.app 1.3.5
3. all necessary components from [official](http://appium.io/slate/en/tutorial/android.html?java#native-android-automation) site
4. Genymotion 2.3.1

my Android settings
[image]

my General settings
[image]

when I check settings with launching doctor all fine

[image]

Launch server 
[image]

But when I launch Inspector I have an error
[image]

**run app with arc**

I have the same error when launching arc from terminal like from [this](https://saucelabs.com/resources/appium-bootcamp/appium-bootcamp-2013-chapter-2-the-console)
[image]

Can you explain me how to correctly use appium? How to run tests and where they should be written? Thanks a lot for any information.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this link to start your first test:

[How to create in Eclipse and run your Appium test on the iOS device (not emulator) where app is installed prior to the execution of the test script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24919159/how-to-create-in-eclipse-and-run-your-appium-test-on-the-ios-device-not-emulato)

Also, to run the Appium inspector you need to have your test in running stage OR you can use UIAutomatorViewer

Comment: Thanks for reply, I saw this post, it's for ios devices and Eclipse. I'm using Android Studio / Android devices-emulators and Appium.app